# Beginner here, I want to do something like this

Tags: 3d-view

First of, I am a completely beginner of Blender 3D. I didn't even touch it in my entire life.

I just finished my Photography And Videography course. I am interested in nature, environments, etc. I am thinking of making a website of photography kind of stuff.

My problem is I can't go to places like beaches, gardens and all that because my town does not have those beautiful things. Suddenly, I came to know about Blender on YouTube. I watched couple of videos showing 3D environments that look so damn real. I mean, ultra HD. Wow! And the best part about that is it has camera to animate it and taking pictures. Since I've done Photography and Videography course, I can easily handle the camera, I guess. The only thing I need to learn is to make environments, camera handling, timeline, shaders, etc. I can grab assets from somewhere.

My question is, from where should I start and what should I do in order to make this dream possible.

Comment: start by watching free online tutorials: https://www.blender.org/support/tutorials/

Comment: We all like a stories :) ... but this site is not suited to your kind of question ... try to ask on https://blenderartists.org Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are a beginner, my recommendation is to watch the full Donut beginner tutorial series of channel Blender Guru on youtube.**In that donut tutorial series, you will learn modeling, some sculpting tools, some modifiers, particles and about materials and texture painting.** Then try to study all the  sculpting tools so that it will help you to make landscapes. you can fins tutorial series about sculpting in youtube. then try modifiers tools too. So first try that donut tutorial esries.

Comment: OP is not interested in modeling skills rather than gathering models and building scenes.